# How to save double data in one field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I have two checkbox and one radio button.
If 2nd checkbox is checked then don't show the radio buttons.
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clients").click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#radio-button-option").addClass('hide');
      } else {
        $("#radio-button-option").removeClass('hide');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="members" name="members" value="members">
<label for="members"> Members</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="clients" name="clients" value="clients">
<label for="clients"> Clients</label><br>

<div id='radio-button-option'>
  <input type="radio" id="client1" name="client1" value="client1">
  <label for="client1">Client1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="client2" name="client2" value="client2">
  <label for="client2">Client2</label><br>
</div>
```

I've a table named 'post'.
There have some field like (id, title, file, **share_with**).
Now i want to save this in database.
Table name post.
And i save this data into **share_with** field.

Generally save 'members' and 'clients'.

If i don't save client  then show this radio button. And if i checked the members and choose the radio1 then save the 'members' and 'radio1'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to save multiple value in single column. you can splite client1 & client2 in comma saperated value or convert into json format then store it.

**But i will not recommend you to do that.**

Instead of store in single column, create new table with id(pk), share_with, Members_id(relation with ur table).

insert two row into this new table, if user selects multiple. Like

- 1 Client1 1
- 2 Client2 1